# Retrofit Error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 58 path $.incidents.asset.suspect

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am getting this JSON back from a request:

```
{"incidents":{"incident_bulletin":[],"asset":{"suspect":[{"suspect_id":363,"asset_id":584,"suspect_skin_color_id":-1,"suspect_height":"67","suspect_weight":"-1","suspect_hair_id":-1,"suspect_ethnicity_id":-1,"other_info":null,"suspect_direction":{"direction_id":-1,"direction":null,"direction_additional_info":""},"suspect_location":{"access_token":null,"location_id":0,"location_latitude":null,"location_longitude":null,"location_zipcode":null,"location_name":null,"location_street":null,"location_city":null,"limit":0},"suspect_age":0,"suspect_gender":null,"suspect_clothing":null,"suspect_scars":null,"suspect_tattoo":null}],"weapons":[],"vehicle":[],"images":[{"image_id":422,"asset_id":584,"image_url":"https://garbageaddress.com/copsapp_picture_29_2015_01_09_02_45_11_76?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFM7HIWC32TO2KEA&Expires=1483958713&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg&Signature=BxDtFEiDAdbZlAR4HSMi7NOxY%2BQ%3D","other_info":null}],"videos":[],"asset_text":null},"access_token":null,"incident_id":257,"incident_location_id":1307,"incident_description":"Burglary","asset_id":584,"incident_occur_datetime_start":"2015-01-09 05:42:47.00","incident_occur_datetime_end":"2015-01-09 12:42:47.00","incident_reported_datetime":"2015-01-09 10:45:58.00","incident_location":{"access_token":null,"location_id":0,"location_latitude":"40.31192","location_longitude":"-112.0059","location_zipcode":"","location_name":"","location_street":"","location_city":"","limit":0},"unread_response_count":0,"total_response_count":0,"incident_radius":0.0,"incident_location_address":"Eagle Mountain, United States.","incident_status":-1,"incident_priority":0,"incident_type":-1}}
```

I am using retrofit to help put my json response into objects. I get this error when I try and do so:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 58 path $.incidents.asset.suspect
```

Here is my suspect array class that it is complaining about:

```
public class SuspectList {

    @SerializedName("suspect")
    private Suspect[] suspect;
```

And here is my suspect class:

```
public class Suspect {

    @SerializedName("suspect_id")
    private Integer suspectID;

    @SerializedName("asset_id")
    private Integer assetID;

    @SerializedName("suspect_skin_color_id")
    private Integer skinColorID;

    @SerializedName("suspect_height")
    private String suspectHeight;

    @SerializedName("suspect_weight")
    private String suspectWeight;

    @SerializedName("suspect_hair_id")
    private Integer hairID;

    @SerializedName("suspect_ethnicity_id")
    private Integer ethnicityID;

    @SerializedName("suspect_direction")
    private Direction direction;

    @SerializedName("suspect_location")
    private Location location;

    @SerializedName("suspect_age")
    private Integer suspectAge;

    @SerializedName("suspect_gender")
    private String suspectGender;

    @SerializedName("suspect_clothing")
    private String suspectClothing;

    @SerializedName("suspect_scars")
    private String suspectScars;

    @SerializedName("suspect_tattoo")
    private String suspectTattoo;
```

Why is it complaining that it expects an object when the JSON shows itas an array? Any ideas of what I can do to fix it?

EDIT: Pretty json
[image]

Comment: your json is not an array but it's an object which contains array. So try BEGIN_OBJECT as it says

Comment: To create pojo for your json data visit [JsonSchema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Do you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Asset` class, remove `SuspectList`, use `Suspect[]` array directly:

```
public class Asset {
    ...
    @SerializedName("suspect")
    private Suspect[] suspect;
}
```